# Does Acumatica have an object to calculate GL Account Summary information?

Tags: acumatica

We are trying to write customization to generate a download GL account summary information from Acumatica to text file.  Need to be able to calculate period summary information (beginning balance, net change, and ending balance for each account using code.  I'm assuming that Acumatica has an object to calculate those values for a specific Financial Period ID...but I dont know what it is.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The information you're looking for is already stored in the GLHistory table. The data is aggregated by ledger, branch, financial period, account and subaccount. This information is updated by accumulator attributes that are used during the GL release process.

Comment: I did a trace and can see the SQL for the aggregation...it would be nice if there was a tool that translated SQL to BQL.  :)